# Adding a custom tab and page MOSS MySites that everyone can see

Tags: sharepoint, mysite

On MOSS mysites I want to be able to create a new tab that every mysite user can view, it should show a web part page.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Create a site collection as a parent to all the MySites. Or to put it the other way, make the MySites a subsite to a site collection that has the site that you want all the MySites to see.

Comment: As far as I know a MySite is a site collection so how would you make a site collection a sub site of a site collection?

Answer (score 1):

In your Shared Services Provider (Central Admin/Shared Services Admin), look under User Profiles and My Sites.  You can select Personalization Site Links and point to an existing site that contains the web part page you want to display.

You can also filter the display using the Audiences functionality so that it only displays to a select group of users.

Comment: Yes, that's good, that gives me an extra tab, do you know how I might get it to remain inside the mysite area and just display the new web part page without leaving the mysite?

Comment: Oh, OK, you mean actually *within* the user's Personal Site?  A Page Viewer Web Part would do the trick in the Personal Site, but you'd probably need to use Feature Stapling to attach it to each user's Personal Site.

I'm not sure the Page Viewer Web Part is available for the Public Profile Page of My Site - though you may be able to import it.

Answer (score 0):

In regards to @Brian Meinertz's comment. This a detailed blog on Microsft's site about feature stapling:

[Customizing MOSS 2007 My Sites within the enterprise](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/blog/Pages/BlogPost.aspx?PageType=4&ListId=%7B72C1C85B-1D2D-4A4A-90DE-CA74A7808184%7D&pID=794)